# xPosition not working for cdkMenu in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I just refactoring my code from `matMenu` to `cdkMenu` and explore that `xPosition='before'` won't work anymore.

I also read the documentation but didn't find how can I position `cdkMenu` if you have any experience with this case please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cdkMenuPosition on the element with cdkMenuTriggerFor directive

cdkMenuPosition takes an array of ConnectionPositionPairs, to achieve the before effect on the menu set the ConnectionPositionPair as below

```html
<button [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="example-standalone-trigger" [cdkMenuPosition]="positions">Click me!</button>
```

```
positions = [
  new ConnectionPositionPair(
    { originX: 'end', originY: 'bottom' },
    { overlayX: 'end', overlayY: 'top' }
  ),
];
```

you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432447/angular-cdk-understanding-the-overlay-position-system) for more info in Global Position Strategy

https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/api#CdkMenuTrigger